# Dependent ComboBox Not Firing for Tab in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a make and a model combo box.  The make combo loads info when the user selects a make.  The problem is, it does not fire when the user tabs off the combobox.  It does work when they press enter or they select an item from the list with the mouse.  Here is what we have for the make combo:

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: 'ddlMake',
    store: makeStore,
    displayField: 'Description',
    valueField: 'MakeOid',
    width: 175,
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Select a make',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    listeners:
        {
            select: function(combo, record, index) {
                LoadModelCombo(combo, record, index);
                FillAircraftType();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're using the value of this field as the source for your model combo, why not keep an eye on the `change` event instead of the `select` event? The docs are a little confusing, implying that this only fires when you call the `setValue` method, but it fires on users' selection in the UI too.

Comment: So you are saying the default listener is just for the select event?  I think what I really need is to listen to blur.  What is the equivalent in ExtJS?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "default listener."  It just sounds from your description that you should be interested in the change event rather than the select event. It seems like you'd be interested in updating your UI for the model combo even if the make combo never loses focus, so blur might not be the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using.  I used both select and change:

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: 'ddlMake',
    store: makeStore,
    displayField: 'Description',
    valueField: 'MakeOid',
    width: 175,
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Select a make',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    listeners: {
        select: function (combo, record, index) {
            LoadModelCombo(combo, record, index);
            FillAircraftType();
        },
        change: function (combo, record, index) {
            LoadModelCombo(combo, record, index);
            FillAircraftType();
        }
    }
}),
```

Answer (score -1):

use **forceSelection** config property of combobox component this would allow you to achive what you want. for rest you can see the sencha documentation of this config